# MongoDB difference between error code 11000 and 11001

Tags: mongodb

According to this *HIGHLY incomplete* list http://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/error-codes/ they're both related to duplicate keys. But I was not able to get a 11001 error. All of the following threw a 11000 error:

- inserting a document with an `_id` that already existed
- inserting a document with duplicate fields where the fields had a compound unique index
- updating a document with said compound unique index

So this goes completely against the linked page, which says 11000 is for `_id` and 11001 would occur on updates (not inserts).

So my question is: When does 11001 occur?

Comment: I can’t find error `11001` at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/base/error_codes.err and that link is dead. Is this question specific to a version of mongo?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The code `11001` does not exist in the 2.5/2.6 branch on GitHub, so if you're trying a 2.5 version than you can't create it. I did have a look at the code, but I can't find any path that shows the `11001` code either directly.

The following few lines will show code `11001`:

```
db.so.drop();
db.so.insert( { foo: 5 } );
db.so.ensureIndex( { foo: 1 }, { unique: true } );
db.so.insert( { foo: 6 } );
```

The expected `11000`:

```
db.so.insert( { foo: 5 } );
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.so.$foo_1  dup key: { : 5.0 }
```

And now to reach the `11001`:

```
db.so.insert( { foo: 6 } );
db.so.update( { foo: 6 }, { $set: { foo: 5 } } );
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.so.$foo_1  dup key: { : 5.0 }
```

Still the original `11000`, but:

```
db.getPrevError();
{
    "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.so.$foo_1  dup key: { : 5.0 }",
    "code" : 11001,
    "n" : 0,
    "nPrev" : 1,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

That the original textual error message shows `E11000` is a bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5978

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm using 2.4.5 and it was in fact just the error message that was wrong (I didn't use `getPrevError`). Does the fact that you couldn't find any `11001` in the source mean they drop it after 2.4? Do you know any source (e.g. an issue) for this?

Comment: No, I couldn't find an issue for that, but I left a comment at that SERVER-5978 issue.

Comment: Thanks for your research. I'm gonna keep checking for both `11000` and `11001` in my client code.

Comment: Based on this answer I gather that the difference between 11000 and 11001 is that they're emitted for inserts and updates respectively? Or is this purely a server version difference?

Comment: Why does the server emit different error codes for these cases? What is the best way to check for either error. Something like `(error.code & ~1) === 11000`?

Answer (score 3):

Mongo has an `ErrorCategory` enum which creates a `DUPLICATE_KEY_ERROR` for the following error codes:

```
private static final List<Integer> DUPLICATE_KEY_ERROR_CODES = Arrays.asList(11000, 11001, 12582);
```

The above is from mongodb java driver 3.6.4.

So both refer to duplicate keys.